# Update table column on view edit

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel and I'm trying to get a table update column value when user is editing his previous input (like oops he messed up and has to edit his order).

My tables:

Materials:

```
| id | name | count_all | count_current | price_unit |
```

Orders:

```
| id | count_order | material_id | invoice_id |
```

My OrderController Update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, order $order){
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $order->delete();
        return redirect('/order');
    }
    else{
        $order->material_id = $request->material_id;
        $order->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
        $order->count_order = $request->count_order;

        $count_order = $request->input('count_order');
        $query = $order->save();
        if($query){
            if($count_order > $request->count_order){
                DB::table('materials')
                    ->where('id', $request->material_id)
                    ->increment('count_all', ($count_order - $request->count_order));
                DB::table('materials')
                    ->where('id', $request->material_id)
                    ->increment('count_current', ($count_order - $request->count_order));
            }
            elseif($count_order < $request->count_order){
                DB::table('materials')
                    ->where('id', $request->material_id)
                    ->decrement('count_all', ($request->count_order - $count_order));
                DB::table('materials')
                    ->where('id', $request->material_id)
                    ->decrement('count_current', ($request->count_order - $count_order));                    
            }
        }
        return redirect('/order');
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Since I wrote similar function for insert to **Orders** table and it updates **Materials count_all** and **count_current**. Now I want to do the same in above code but for when somebody edits that order (can write an example if my question is not clear).

**EDIT**
Example what I want to achieve and to be clear editing existing order works.
If somebody added order for 20 Pens we have a order that will look like:

```
| 1 (12345 - invoice_id) | 1 (Pen - material_id - which will correspond Pens id from Materials table) | 20 (count_order) |
```

So when the order is made it updates value in **Materials** table which is:

```
| id = 1 | Pen | count_all + 20 | count_current + 20 | 1$ |
```

it means that when you make order the **count_all** and **count_current** will increase with value of the **count_order**. Now when I will edit my order because I made a mistake and I wanted to order 15 Pens not 20 it should accordingly substract (or add if value is bigger) from **Materials** table so the value in columns will be right.

Function that handles inserts in the Controller is:

```
public function insert(Request $request){

    $order = new order;

    $order->material_id = $request->material_id;
    $order->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
    $order->count_order = $request->count_order;

    $query = $order->save();
    if($query){
        DB::table('materials')
            ->where('id', $request->material_id)
            ->increment('count_all', $request->count_order);
        DB::table('materials')
            ->where('id', $request->material_id)
            ->increment('count_current', $request->count_order);
    }
    return redirect('/order');
}
```

Comment: Can you mention the result or error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I edit the order but it doesn't update value in Materials table. So... just my code isn't working.

Comment: What is the order here? `public function update(Request $request, order $order)` Model?

Comment: $order is the value of corresponding row in Orders table (so for example id 2, count_order 10, material_id 1, invoice_id 1 - it is what you want to edit).

Answer (score 1):

This is simplified version. First test if this updates both orders and materials table

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $order->delete();
        return redirect('/order');
    }
    else{
        $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
        $order->material_id = $request->material_id;
        $order->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
        $order->count_order = $request->count_order;
        $order->save();

        $materialID = $request->material_id;
        $countOrder = $request->count_order;

        DB::table('materials')
            ->where('id', $materialID)
            ->increment('count_all', $countOrder);
        DB::table('materials')
            ->where('id', $materialID )
            ->increment('count_current', $countOrder);     

        return redirect('/order');
   }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167639/discussion-between-ahsan-and-korni).